# hyperlink in echo to pass data to new PHP page

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink

I have a databases of courses and I can return the courses the way I want to. I am having trouble figuring out how to hyperlink the name of the course so that I can display only that courses data on a new page (full.php). I want to grab the course ID and on the full.php use this as my WHERE statement to display additional fields.

below is what I have tried:

```
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Course ID</th>
<th>Course Name</th>
<th>Provider Type</th>
<th>Audience</th>
<th>Provider Track</th>
<th>Course Delivery</th>

</tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <p> <strong>Course Name:</strong><a href=Full.php?name='".$courseID."'>". $row['courseName'] ."</a> </p>
             <p> <strong>Course Number:</strong>".$row['courseNumber']." </p
             <p> ".$row['courseDescription'] . " </p>
             <p> <strong>Course Length:</strong> " .$row['courseLength'] . " </p>
      </td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseProviderType'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseAudience'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseTrack'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseDelivery'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }


echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: <a href=Full.php?name='".$row['courseID']."'>". $row['courseName'] ."</a>
replace it
<a href=Full.php?name='".$courseID."'>". $row['courseName'] ."</a>

Comment: $courseID is not defined in your script, try replacing it with: $row['courseID']

Comment: Thank you! Once I figured out to substitute courseId for name it works - I am very new to PHP (we will call it a learning curve)

Answer (score 0):

You forget the $row variable on the link.
Here is a fix :

```
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Course ID</th>
<th>Course Name</th>
<th>Provider Type</th>
<th>Audience</th>
<th>Provider Track</th>
<th>Course Delivery</th>

</tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <p> <strong>Course Name:</strong><a href=Full.php?name='".$row['courseID']."'>". $row['courseName'] ."</a> </p>
             <p> <strong>Course Number:</strong>".$row['courseNumber']." </p
             <p> ".$row['courseDescription'] . " </p>
             <p> <strong>Course Length:</strong> " .$row['courseLength'] . " </p>
      </td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseProviderType'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseAudience'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseTrack'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['courseDelivery'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }


echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

On your second page, you can get this value with the global $_GET variable `$_GET['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest passing the course id directly from the database row:

```
<a href=Full.php?name='".$row['courseID']."'>". $row['courseName'] ."</a>
```

and maybe changing the attribute name for clarity:

```
<a href=Full.php?courseID='".$row['courseID']."'>". $row['courseName'] ."</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
 <a href=Full.php?name='".$row['courseID']."'>". $row['courseName'] ."</a>
```

and missing tag

```
<p> <strong>Course Number:</strong>".$row['courseNumber']." </p>
```